# Extracting KLV data from mp2 stream using C++ and ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, metadata

I have an mp2 stream that has klv metadata.  I stored the klv in a file using ffmpeg command line:

ffmpeg -i input.mpg -map data-re -codec copy -f data output.klv

I now want to do this in c++.  So, I have

FFMPEG setup …..

Then the main loop

```
// Read frames
while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0)
{
    // Is this a packet from the video stream?
    if(packet.stream_index == videoStream)
    {
        // Decode video frame
        avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

        // Did we get a video frame?
        if(frameFinished)
        {
            // Convert the image from its native format to RGB
            sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data,
                                pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height,
                                pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);

            QImage myImage(pFrameRGB->data[0], pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, QImage::Format_RGB888);

            QPixmap img(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage.scaled(ui->label->width(),ui->label->height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio)));

            ui->label->setPixmap(img);
            QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        }
    }
    else // klv stream
    {
        // Decode klv data
        qDebug() << packet.buf->size;
        for(int i=0; i<packet.buf->size; i++)
        {
            qDebug() << packet.buf->data[i];
        }
    }
```

The resulting klv output is different - I must be doing something wrong processing the packet.  The frames are good and I'm viewing it in a qt label - so my ffmpeg setup is working on images but not the klv data.

Comment: what is the output you are getting? what are you expecting? does the file contain only video and klv? no audio?

Comment: I just have video and klv data - no sound.  I'm getting a series of integers -  but it doesn't correspond to the output.klv which is asci characters - I convert the asci characters to integers and they do dot correlate.

Comment: @Douglas Can you share the rest of your code as well as I am trying to do something similar?

Comment: I'm not working for the company - so I don't have the source code.  Sorry

Comment: Check using notepad++ as I indicated below

Comment: @Douglas I tried to open both the output from the program(integer values stored as .txt) and ffmpeg output(.klv/.bin - looks like ACSII values). Can you help me with how to correlate them on notepad++? I am not sure if both of them are the same? I would need the output to look like the ffmpeg output(.klv/.bin format). How did you make sense of the ffmpeg output in notepad++ which for me is .klv/.bin format?

Answer (score 0):

My bad - this code is working - I was comparing the int output to the ffmpeg output being viewed in notepad - when I used notepad++ - I can make sense of the ffmpeg output and it does correlate :)